# Silex infinite-redirect routing issue with mounted ControllerProviders

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, routes, silex

I am trying to mount a book-register under `domain.tld/list` which should print the default list when nothing is appended other than `/list`, but also provide actions including parameters like for example:

- `domain.tld/list`
- `domain.tld/list/`
- `domain.tld/list?q=search`
- `domain.tld/list/?q=search`
- `domain.tld/list/following`
- `domain.tld/list/following?sort=date`
- `domain.tld/list/following/?sort=date`

I use Silex Version 2.2.2

controllers.php:

```
...
$app->mount('/', new \Controllers\IndexController());
$app->mount('/list', new \Controllers\BookListController());
$app->mount('/info', new \Controllers\BookInfoController());
...
```

BookListController.php:

```
class BookListController implements ControllerProviderInterface
{
    public function connect(Application $app)
    {
        /** @var ControllerCollection $ctrl */
        $ctrl = $app['controllers_factory'];
        $ctrl->get('/', 'Controllers\BookListController::listAction')->bind('book_list');
        $ctrl->get('/following', 'Controllers\BookListController::listAction');
        return $ctrl;
    }

    function listAction(Application $app)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**The issue:**

- calling domain.tld/list and domain.tld/list/ gets in an infinite redirection loop between the route with trailing / and without.

[image: screenshot]

**Webserver conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/***/web

    <Directory "/var/www/***/web">
            Options +FollowSymlinks
            AllowOverride All
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            Require all granted
            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                    Options -MultiViews
                    RewriteEngine On

                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
                    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
            </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    php_flag log_errors on
    php_flag display_errors on
    php_value error_log /var/log/*****

</VirtualHost>
```

Where is the misconfiguration? Is this possible with mount or do I need to use another method to register these routes?

Comment: Just a reminder, [Silex will reach EOL on June 2018](http://symfony.com/blog/the-end-of-silex)

Comment: I have the same problem